# Determine kernel

Tags: linear-algebra

$\mathbb{R}[x]_n \subset C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ being the $\mathbb{R}$-Vectorspace of real Polynomial Functions $x \mapsto p(x)$ with deg $p(x) \leq n$ and for $s_1,...s_m \in \mathbb{R}$ let
$$f:\mathbb{R}[x]_n \to \mathbb{R}^m, p(x)\mapsto (p(s_i))_{i=1,...,m}$$

I have to show that $f$ is linear and determine $ker f$.

The way I understand it right now, I take a polynomial and just substitute $x$ with the $s_i$ for the respective dimension and keep the coefficients. If that is correct it is easy to prove that $f$ is linear.

$ker f$ would be $\{p(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]_n :(\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_ks_i^k =0)_{i=1,...m} \}$
but I am struggeling to simplify that. I think the right place to start is to write it as system of $m$ equations where we want to determine the koeficients given the $s_i$.

\begin{bmatrix}
a_ns_1^n & a_1s_1^{n-1}& ... & a_1s_1 & -a_0\\
a_ns_2^n  & a_1s_2^{n-1}& ... & a_1s_2 & -a_0 \\
:  & : & : & :&:   \\
a_ns_m^n  & a_{n-1}s_m^{n-1}& ... &a_1s_m & -a_0
\end{bmatrix}

Hints would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: If $f(s)=0$, $f$ is divisible by $x-s$.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know whether $n \leq m$ or visa versa.

Namely if $m \leq n$ you can construct your kernel with the zeros:
$p(x)=(s_1-x)\cdot ... \cdot(s_m-x) \in ker f$ .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).